# Null Pointer Exception while using insertNewFilterColoumn method

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, xml-schema-collection

I was trying to filter one Column using CTAutoFilter. The table (sample table, not the actual one ) value is as follows :

```
Brand           Color   Round Neck
Louis Philippe  White   Yes
Peter England   White   Yes
Van Huesen      White   No
Arrow New York  White   No
```

I want to filter the 3rd coloumn with the value "Yes". So I wrote the following code. But I'm getting null pointer exception on

```
CTFilterColumn  myFilterColumn=sheetFilter.insertNewFilterColumn(0);
```

The code is :

```
try 
    {
        xlsxFile = new FileInputStream("D:/Automation/Sample1.xlsx");
        xssfWB = new XSSFWorkbook(xlsxFile);
        sheet = xssfWB.getSheetAt(0);
        CTAutoFilter sheetFilter=sheet.getCTWorksheet().getAutoFilter();
        CTFilterColumn  myFilterColumn=sheetFilter.insertNewFilterColumn(0);
        myFilterColumn.setColId(3L);
        CTFilter myFilter = myFilterColumn.addNewFilters().insertNewFilter(0);
        myFilter.setVal("Yes");
        for(Row r : sheet)
        {
            for(Cell c : r)
            {
                if (c.getColumnIndex()==3 && !c.getStringCellValue().equals("Yes"))
                {
                    row = (XSSFRow) c.getRow();
                    if(row.getRowNum()!=0)
                    {
                        row.getCTRow().setHidden(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

can anyone help me to sort this out??

Comment: The `sheet.getCTWorksheet().getAutoFilter()` may return `null` if there is not actually a AutoFilter set to the sheet.

Comment: Because there is not actually a AutoFilter set to the sheet. Open the sheet using Excel and set AutoFilter. Then `sheet.getCTWorksheet().getAutoFilter()` will not be `null`.

Comment: What do you think for what column `c.getColumnIndex()==3` will be true? [Cell.getColumnIndex](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getColumnIndex--) "Returns: **zero**-based column index of a column in a sheet". So it will be true for column `D`. Same for `setColId`.

Comment: I iterated over each line and the code is working properly except the getCTRow().setHidden(true) method and because of this, it is not getting filtered. Is it the problem with jar file or anything else?

Comment: So the column `Round Neck` having the "Yes" and "No" as content ist column `D` in your sheet?

Comment: yes and i want to hide those which are "No"

Comment: What is in column `A` then? And is column `A` part of the AutoFilter? Because if not, the `myFilterColumn.setColId(3L)` is the wrong column then. And what means "working properly except the getCTRow().setHidden(true) method" exactly? Any errors? Yust tested: If the AutoFilter is from column `A` to column `D` and column `D` is the column with "Yes" and "No", then your code should work.

Comment: the table here is just a sample one as the one I'm working is related to my client. The problem which I'm facing now is that except the statement **row.getCTRow().setHidden(true);**, the remaining code is working perfectly. The rows which has the value **No** at the 3rd coloumn are not getting hidden.

Comment: You seems not to understand. Are you sure, the code line `row.getCTRow().setHidden(true);` will be executed at all? How have you checked this? As said column index is 0 based. So first column `A` is index 0, second column `B` is index 1 and third column `C` is index 2. So if the "Yes"/"No" column is third column `C`, then `if (c.getColumnIndex()==3 && !c.getStringCellValue().equals("Yes"))` will never be true since column index 3 is fourth column `D`.

Comment: The **Yes/No** column is is fourth column **D** only.